Large difference in results when changing batch size
I have a simple convolutional network for mnist data classification in pytorch. I followed up everything in a tutorial that I was watching except the batch size. In tutorial batch_size=100 and I chose batch_size=64
The answers were completely different after training:
Tutorial Result (batch size = 100)
epoch : 1
training loss: 0.6620, acc 83.8433 
validation loss: 0.2735, validation acc 92.2300 
epoch : 2
training loss: 0.2404, acc 93.1217 
validation loss: 0.1942, validation acc 94.7000 
epoch : 3
training loss: 0.1717, acc 95.1583 
validation loss: 0.1447, validation acc 95.8700 
epoch : 4
training loss: 0.1295, acc 96.3567 
validation loss: 0.1081, validation acc 96.9000 
epoch : 5
training loss: 0.1047, acc 97.0800 
validation loss: 0.0922, validation acc 97.3300 

My Result (batch size = 64)
epoch : 1
training loss: 0.5125, acc 55.5245 
validation loss: 0.2263, validation acc 59.5732 
epoch : 2
training loss: 0.1936, acc 60.3731 
validation loss: 0.1542, validation acc 60.8599 
epoch : 3
training loss: 0.1293, acc 61.6034 
validation loss: 0.1040, validation acc 61.8089 
epoch : 4
training loss: 0.0986, acc 62.1642 
validation loss: 0.0882, validation acc 62.0191 
epoch : 5
training loss: 0.0812, acc 62.5043 
validation loss: 0.0761, validation acc 62.1911

why did this happen? Is it possible that my configuration caused the model stuck in local minima?
I looked up in pytorch forums 1, 2 and stackoverflow 1
I changed the default tensor precision torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.DoubleTensor)  but the issue still exist.
